# How can I convert a string "12 June 2020" date to UTC format using date() or moment()?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

`12 June 2020` to something like S`at Feb 01 2020 13:28:38 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)` and ıt will be 4 languages, de, tr, en, ru. I ve tried date.js to parse but couldnt get it work

Comment: `new Date("12 June 2020")`

Comment: use moment, because browsers dont' necessarily support that format

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: stackoverflow is not just for asking, try searching it as well, you will find a lot of good answers for simple questions like this.

Comment: ofc I ve been trying for 2 days, ı am running a big serious project, lastly ı couldnt fix this problem as ı said ı tried date.js using moment.js so ı just need to convert "12 June 2020" to Feb 01 2020 13:28:38 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) but somehow its not working in my codes, ı would like to share my codes but its too much for asking Kaushik

Comment: For local time in ISO 8601 format: `moment('12 June 2020', 'DD MMMM YYYY').format()`. For UTC time in ISO 8601 format: `moment('12 June 2020', 'DD MMMM YYYY').utc().format()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = new Date('12 June 2020').toString();
console.log(d);
```